# 2 values expected value problem

Tags: statistics

A bank account has 1000 dollars and get's a 5% interest daily. Every day the account has $0.405$ probability to lose $20$ dollars.

What's the mean of the amount of money in the acount after 2 days?

I thought about calculating $((1000-20*0.405)*1.05-20*0.405)*1.05$

But I think it might be wrong because the probabiltity changes depending on the previous day.
I mean that the probability to lose in both days is $0.405^2$, one day lose and the other no lose would be $0.405*(1-0.405)$ to my understaing, so I would need to take it into acount somehow but don't know how.

thank you.

Comment: The 20 \$ are lost, when they get lost, before or after applying the $1.0105$ multiplication rate?

Comment: before multiplication rate

Comment: Not sure I see the problem.  There are only $4$ scenarios, yes?  According to whether the Loss happens ($L$) on a given day or not ($W$), we have $LL$, $LW$, $WL$ or $WW$.  Just work out the final cash in each case.

Comment: final cash for each case and than sum it all up?

Comment: Well, they don't have the same probability, so no.  You have to weight each case by the probability of its occurrence.

Comment: Can mean be returned by a value which isn't a final number but a table in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.  The mean is a number.

Comment: @MisheMitasek I haven't touched any mathematics for years, so please make sure my answer is correct before using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four possibilities.

1. Loses 20\$ on the first day but not on the second day
2. Loses 20\$ on the second day but not on the first day
3. Loses 20\$ on both days
4. Loses nothing on both day

Calculate the amount in each case, $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and $A_4$. Now to get the mean value, you just multiple each amount with its probability of happening.
$$A = A_1\cdot 0.405\cdot (1-0.405) + A_2\cdot (1-0.405)\cdot 0.405 + A_3\cdot0.405\cdot0.405 + A_4(1-0.405)(1-0.405)$$

Answer (score 2):

Two days are a small horizon. The random part is modelled by the binomial tree:

```
                        * [L] (1000-20)*r - 20 ... and finally ((1000-20)*r -20)*r
                      /
       * [L] 1000-20  - * [K] (1000-20)*r      ... and finally (1000-20)*r*r
      /
1000 *                 * [L] 1000 * r - 20     ... and finally (1000*r -20)*r
      \              / 
       * [K] 1000    - * [K] 1000 * r          ... and finally 1000*r*r
```

with `[L]` used for `LOSE`, and `[K]` for `KEEP`.
Let $p$ be the probability for losing, i.e. for the `[L]` ramifications, and $q$ the complementary probability.

Above, the multiplication rate is (EDIT: adjusted after the edit in the OP)
$$
r = 1 + 5\% =1.05\ .
$$
The mean amount of money after two days is thus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
M
&=
p^2\cdot((1000-20)r-20)r
+pq\cdot(1000-20)r^2
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+pq\cdot(1000r-20)r
+q^2\cdot 1000r^2
\\
&=1000r^2-20p^2(r+r^2)-20pq(r+r^2)
\\
&=1000r^2-20p(r+r^2)(p+q)
\\
&=1000r^2-20p(r+r^2)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

*Later EDIT:*

An other way to think about this is as in the OP. The mean value after two days is by linearity $1000r^2$ plus mean value of the possible loss.

- The probability to lose $20\$$ in the first day is $p$, and the corresponding mean is $p\cdot  r^2\cdot 20\$$, using the convention that we "first lose, then use the daily rate".
- The probability to lose $20\$$ in the second day is $p$ again, and the corresponding mean is $p\cdot  r\cdot 20\$$, using the same convention.

So the mean, computed as in the OP comes to the same value:
$$1000 r^2 -20pr^2-20pr\qquad\text{(dollars)}\ .$$

Comment: So my answer is wrong then, right?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong, but for an other (minor) reason. The daily multiplication factor is $r=1+1.05\%=1.0105$, and using it, your answer is in my notation the same one, $$1000r^2-20pr^2-20pr\ .$$

Comment: my aplogies the interest is 5%, so I just multiply the amount in the end of the day wether loss or no by 1.05 and then by the probability of ll,,kk,lk,kl right?

Comment: Yes, in this case use the absolute multiplication factor $r=1.05$, everything is all right.